# Not importing class

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in React Js don't judge me bad for it. I was writing some class to learn but unfortunately I can't export and import one of my class.

```
import React from "react";

class Yozuvla extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <p>Ismingiz</p>
                <p>Familyagiz</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Yozuvla;
```

Here is the second class  which can't be imported

```
import React from "react";
import yozuv from "./components/Form";
class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
      return (
          <div>
        <yozuv/>
          </div>
      );
    }
}
export default App;
```

yozuv class don't show up why.browser is white like snow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classname should be in `PascalCase`,

```
import yozuv from "./components/Form";
```

this should be

```
import Yozuv from "./components/Form";
```

Usage

```
<Yozuv/>
```

When you add any element like `<yozuv/>` (starts with small letter), react takes it as a normal `HTML` tag and **NOT** a `React Component`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
// make sure the location of file is the same  for Yozuvla 
import Yozuvla from'./components/Form'
 class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Yozuvla/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

tell me in commit it work or not